# How to resize card content to its size in material ui?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts, material-ui

I would like to provide material ui cards in a grid, which contain highcharts as in this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/30l4r1y601). If you fix the size of the cards, the content does not adjust properly. That is the first issue I do not how to solve?

The second issue is that both cards feature different content and I would like to know how to best make both cards equal in size if I do not set a certain size in pixels such it fits to all screen sizes?

```
const styles = (theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    card: {
      width: "200px",
      height: "222px"
    }
  });

class TestCardTwo extends React.Component<WithStyles<typeof styles>> {
  render() {
    return (
      <Card className={this.props.classes.card}>
        <CardHeader titleTypographyProps={{ variant: "h6" }} title="Headline" />
        <CardContent>
          <TestChart />
          <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
            Word of the Day
        </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In API we can read:

> **height: number, string, null**
>
> ...
>
> By default (when null) the height is calculated from the offset height of the containing element, or 400 pixels if the containing element's height is 0.

So your charts are 400px high, you should set correct height for the chart or chart container. Similar issue: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n3wcLhxs/

To adjust the card size to the entire screen height you can use `vh` units:

```
card: {
  height: "100vh"
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-pine-4mx-4mxng?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: live demo is broken

Comment: Hi @ali al-karaawi, Thanks for the info! Here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-pine-4mx-4mxng?file=/src/App.tsx is the fixed one.